# Angular Material Autocomplete MatAutocompleteTrigger

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can someone please explain to me how does the `MatAutocompleteTrigger` work?

```
@ViewChild('autocompleteInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) triggerAutocompleteInput: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

<mat-form-field>
  <input
    #autocompleteInput
    matInput
    placeholder="Label"
    formControlName="label"
    [matAutocomplete]="autocompletePanel"
  >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #autocompletePanel="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let item of items | async"
    [value]="item.label"
  >
    {{ item.label }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>

this.triggerAutocompleteInput.optionSelections.subscribe(option => {
      console.log('Im gonna kill myself', option );
    });
```

It doesn't do anything. I can be selecting options all day long and nothing will fire. **Shouldn't the subscription receive data when I click some option?** The `this.triggerAutocompleteInput.panelClosingActions` works only when you have the autocomplete panel active and you close it with blur.

I don't understand the behavior and I don't understand the documentation.

**And what about if you need to access the input through `nativeElement`?** You can't do it when you use it as `MatAutocompleteTrigger` as far as I can tell.

I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

First off, some preface:

`MatAutocompleteTrigger` functions primarily as a template directive. It 'holds' the input element and provides a point to render the `MatAutocomplete` options defined elsewhere.

`optionSelections` will emit a stream of values, but it won't emit null values. It's a stream that comes from the `MatAutocompleteComponent`. In your component, you'll want to `subscribe` to the emitter `afterContentInit`, when the autocomplete components have finished their own lifecycle logic.

Next, it looks like you're binding `[value]` to `let item.label`. You don't need to put the `let` in there; this is just declaring an unassigned variable and is equivalent to being `null`. Since `optionSelections` emits this `[value]` associated with the option, and since the value passed here is null, you won't get any emissions.

Lastly, since the options selections are known to the `MatAutocompleteComponent` but only passed by reference to the `MatAutocompleteTrigger`, it's my opinion that it's better to get these events from the `MatAutocompleteComponent`, partly because those properties belong to that component, but mostly because `MatAutocompleteComponent` has its own `(optionSelected)` EventEmitter that can be template-bound:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    #autocompleteInput
    matInput
    placeholder="Label"
    formControlName="label"
    [matAutocomplete]="autocompletePanel"
  >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #autocompletePanel="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="doStuff($event)">
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let item of items | async"
    [value]="item.label"
  >
    {{ item.label }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>


public doStuff(e: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) { /* stuff */ }
```

Also, you have `exercise.label` bound to the `<mat-option>` template value. Not sure if that's a typo, but in your provided code `exercise` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Oh shoot. Sorry, the `let item.label` is error in copying. I have only `[value]="item.label"` in my code. Also the `exercise.label`, is ok in my code. I wanted to anonymize it and didn't do a great job. I was using `optionSelected`, but when I was `binding` the `label` to the `value`, I was also getting only `label` in optionSelected and not the whole object. But if I can do it as you have shown in your example, that will do just fine. Thank you. Did you down-vote my answer? If yes, can you tell me why please? Thank you very much for your help. I'll fix errors in my example.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `(optionSelected)="doStuff($event)"` event holds value of the label only, not the whole object.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, and I don't know why you were downvoted. One thing to note is that `optionSelected` will also contained the value bound to the `mat-option`'s `[value]`. So, to get the whole object, just bind `[value]="item"`. You can alter how the option is displayed via the template binding `{{ item.label }}` or with the `[displayWith]` display function you already have.

Comment: Yes I can do that, I had that already, BUT then the whole object will be stored in the form. Not just the label string. I don't want that, it feels filthy. :/

Comment: @Laker yeah, it's good to be aware of that, but here's the thing: the whole object is tracked by  `*ngFor`. It's still 'there' and being tracked by change detection. Binding it to the option is only passing it by reference, not by value-it's not being duplicated. Binding just a key of the object still tracks that as a property of the object, not by value. If you wanted to slim down the object before binding, you could `filter()` the stream before the repeat -- the `async` pipe automatically takes care of unsubscribing and cleanup